# Doctrine: Should I create an intermediate entity for many to many relation?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

On recent meeting I got a requirement that for all many-to-many relations, we should create intermediate entity and have many-to-one and one-to-many relations.
For example, we have entities "User" and "Role". I need to create an intermediate entity "UserRole".

```php
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=UserRole::class, mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $userRole;
}
```

```php
class UserRole
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="userRole")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="userRole")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $role;
}
```

```php
class Role
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=UserRole::class, mappedBy="role")
     */
    private $userRole;
}
```

I know that this approach is used by some developers in case when there are some extra parameters in the UserRole entity, but in the example above - no. Is there some doctrine official recommendations or best practiced regarding it? What are pros and cons?

Answer (score 1):

Other than the biggest pro you mentioned, so possibility to enhance the relation with additional fields, there aren't any relevant pros I can think of.

A con is that Doctine/Symfony + DoctrineBundle execute more code to register additional entity, repository for it, etc. It makes the application slightly less optimal. Another one is that your file list may become large if you have a lot of many-to-many intermediate entities, one per file.

I would say you should use regular many-to-many mappings, unless you want to save time on refactors in the future because you're sure or almost sure that the relations will be extended.